# How to email a datatable content as a pdf? Is there any way to do this?

Tags: javascript, datatable

I have a js datatable all good and functioning. Now i need a Email button which would save the content as pdf and send as an email(or atleast attach it to mail).

Is there any way to do it at all?

Below is the datatable. I have added a button saying Email. But it is of no purpose now since im not sure how to proceed on saving as pdf and then sending as an email.

Suggest.

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  var myTable= $('#result_table').DataTable( {
"processing": true,
 //Get the data array as the data for the datatable
"aaData" : pageresult,
"autoWidth": false,
"iDisplayLength": 50, //Set default number of rows to be displayed.
"dom": '<"container"Tlf>tipr', //dom positioning for datatable elements
 "tableTools": { //tabletools is a datatable plugin for features like copy,csv,pdf,print etc.
      "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.0/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
      "aButtons": [{
            "sExtends": "text",
            "sButtonText": "Email",
            "sToolTip": "Send Email"
            },
           "print",
           "copy",
            {
                "sExtends":    "collection",
                "sButtonText": "Download",
                "sToolTip": "Download Options",
                "aButtons":    [ "csv", "xls", "pdf"]
            }
          ],
       },
 //Define title and value for each column of the datatable
"aoColumnDefs" : 
   [
        {
            "sTitle":"TEST RUN DATE",
            "aTargets": [ 0 ],
        },
       {
            "sTitle":"TEST STATUS",
            "aTargets": [ 2 ],
            //Get the data for the cell by this function createdCell.
            //Based on the data returned we have determined the color of the cell.
            createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) 
            {
                  if (cellData=='FAILURE') $(td).css('background-color', 'red');
                  if (cellData=='SUCCESS') $(td).css('background-color', 'green');
            }
        },
        {
            "sTitle":"JOB DETAILS",
            "aTargets": [ 3 ],
        },
        {
            "sTitle":"STARTED AT (HH:MM:SS:MS)",
            "aTargets": [ 9 ],
        },
        {
            "sTitle":"ENDED AT (HH:MM:SS:MS)",
            "aTargets": [ 10 ],
        },
        ]};
```

Comment: generating pdf and ssending an e-mail typically needs server-side support. You may want to take a look at the following reporting server:

[jsreport](http://jsreport.net/)

Comment: I'll have a look. Thanks a lot. @VladimirM